# Quickly drawing shapes with grid inside in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw  a lot of simple things (i. e. polygons with vertices on the grid) like this one.
[image]
Right now my code is made with many uses of Ctrl+c ctrl+v and multicursor and looks like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[gray] (1,0) --++ (0,3);
        \draw[gray] (2,0) --++ (0,1);
        \draw[gray] (3,0) --++ (0,1);
        \draw[gray] (0,1) --++ (2,0);
        \draw[gray] (0,2) --++ (2,0);
        \draw[very thick] (0,0) --++ (0,3) --++ (2,0) --++ (0,-2) --++ (2,0) --++ (0,-1) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It gets even worse for bigger shapes. Is there any way to make the process easier, e. g. generate grid, but show only the part of it that is indside the polygon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw a grid and `\clip` it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip (0,0) |- ++(2,3) |- ++(2,-2) |- cycle;
        \draw[step=1.0,gray] (0,0) grid (3,3);
        \draw[very thick] (0,0) |- ++(2,3) |- ++(2,-2) |- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can simplify path typing with perpendicular segments `(0,0)|-++(2,3)|-++(2,-2)|-cycle;`

Answer (score 3):

Simple code for the simple picture.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2,3) (2,0) grid (4,1);
\draw (0,0)-|(4,1)-|(2,3)-|cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and short. If you don't care about emphasizing the outline, a simple `\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2,3) (2,0) grid (4,1);` does it.